# UI Prototyping Tool which generates html as output

Tags: html, prototyping

I'm looking for a UI prototyping tool which generates HTML output. I checked SO for Web UI prototyping tools, but none of them generates html as output.

Please could you suggest a tool for the same...

Answer (score 7):

[Pencil](https://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/) should fit your bill.

Note: Version 2.0.5 of the plugin works with Firefox 32 (I tried it) despite the web page saying it works only with 3.0-3.6.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain how to export it as html

Comment: An image says more than 1000 words: http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/ScreenShots/ShotDetail.aspx?DocumentPath=screenshots/shots/exporting-document

Comment: The 'see this answer' link is dead again

Comment: @icc97 Someone decided that a question with 133 upvotes, 46 answers with many upvotes "is not constructive".

Comment: Wow :( Cheers for the reply, Pencil is pretty awesome thankfully.

Answer (score 3):

[Axure](http://axure.com) is a very good prototyping tool that generates HTML output.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [App Sketcher](http://www.appwork.com) (currently at release candidate) to see if it fits your need. It is a rapid HTML prototyping tool for creating wireframe and interactive web application prototypes. It uses an embedded webkit browser as design surface so you can use actual HTML components, jQuery UI components and web widgets in design. Users can run/test prototype in their default browser and export the HTML source once they are satisfied with the design.

I am the developer of this application. So sorry about this shameless self promotion. Nevertheless, I do think it can be a useful HTML prototyping tool and worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

For free applications, I suggest **[Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/)**. It can export HTML format in a single HTML page, with some images in other folders. (besides, it can export PDF, ODT, PNG, SVG and so on ). It is opensource, and developed base on Mozilla's XULRunner.

You can install templates for the export. I like “Tab Navigation” the mode. But the interactive is not too much.

For commercial applications. I suggest **[Axure RP](http://www.axure.com/)**. It can export interactive HTML, and very powerful. Please take a look at his demo video first.

Another commercial applications is **Justinmind Prototyper**. If you want the function of exporting HTML, you should buy the Pro version. The free version can not export HTML, but only png/pdf.

BTW, you could google for the words "*prototype software list*" or "*gui prototype software*". You could find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Fireworks does this, http://tv.adobe.com/watch/fireworks-tips-and-tricks/rapid-prototyping/

I think you can make pretty complicated demos with Axure http://www.axure.com/features and Balsamiq http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups also does simple demos.